# Convert currency base from one base to another

Tags: arithmetic

Consider a list of currency rates where the base is USD:

```
1 USD = 

0.90390 EUR
0.74771 GBP
1.30101 CAD
```

how can I convert the base from USD to GBP, such that I end up with:

```
1 GBP = 

1.33767 USD
1.20993 EUR
1.74146 CAD
```

What kind of formula do I need to apply to each rate to convert the base?
Note: rates are taken from xe.com and the desired output example might not be exactly correct.

Comment: Just divide by rate of the desired new base.(Here,GBP,so divide by 0.74771).Why did you put the complex numbers tag?

Comment: @TushantMittal thanks, that works. If you post an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Point of information: complex numbers are numbers with nonzero real part and nonzero imaginary part. When talking about money, the numbers are real numbers, in the mathematical sense, however much they may be imaginary in the colloquial sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it as an answer to close the question,

Divide by rate of the desired new base.
Here it is GBP, so divide by 0.74771.